# Docker-compose multiple ports expose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

My question is about expose multiple ports in one line from an `ENV` variable example, and these ports are not sequential, the same ports from host are going to be the same on container.

```sh
PORTS=80
PORTS=80,443
PORTS=80 443
```

And expose them in `docker-compose`.

according to [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports), you can do.

```
ports:
 - "3000"
 - "3000-3005"
 - "8000:8000"
 - "9090-9091:8080-8081"
 - "49100:22"
 - "127.0.0.1:8001:8001"
 - "127.0.0.1:5000-5010:5000-5010"
 - "6060:6060/udp"
```

But i would like to do it another variable way

```
ports:
  - ${PORTS}:${PORTS}
#Sometimes this will be 
ports:
  - 80:80

#Other times this will be
ports:
  - 80,443:80,443 # Is this possible?
ports:
  - 80-443:80-443 # Don't want this because will export all the ports between
ports:
  - 80 443:80 443 # I think this is wrong syntax
```

Any clue or any other idea?

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you cannot specify the `ports` mapping dynamically.

The Docker Compose YAML file is mostly a static configuration.

One way to address your problem is to generate the (`ports` section) YAML file.

You could and use a tool like `sed` to replace a variable in your Compose file with some generated output.

Suppose you have `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
  service:
    ...
    {{PORTS}}
```

Then

```sh
# List of ports to create
PORTS="80 443 8888"

# Generates "80:80""443:443""8888:8888" NB no commas between items
PORTS=$(for PORT in ${PORTS}; do printf '"%s:%s"' ${PORT} ${PORT}; done)

# Separate items with commas
PORTS=$(echo ${PORTS} | sed 's|""|","|g')

# Finalize the syntax for ports
PORTS="ports: [${PORTS}]"

# Replace {{TEMPLATE}} with the result
sed "s|{{PORTS}}|${PORTS}|g" docker-compose.yaml > docker-compose.new.yaml
```

Would yield `docker-compose.new.yaml`:

```
  service:
    ...
    ports: ["80:80","443:443","8888:8888"]
```

It's not very elegant but it should suffice.

**NB** I'm generating the ports as JSON for convenience (to avoid problems with newlines). YAML is a superset of JSON so you can use JSON instead of YAML for Docker Compose files.

Google (my employer) has a very nice tool for generating JSON (!) using a JSON-based templating language: [Jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/). Because YAML is a superset of JSON, you may use JSON instead of YAML in your Docker Compose files.

Jsonnet:

```
local ports = ["80", "443", "8888"]; 
{"service":{
    "ports": [
        port + ":" + port
        for port in ports
    ]
}}
```

Generates:

```
{
  "service": {
    "ports": [
      "80:80",
      "443:443",
      "8888:8888"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution using Jsonnet. But, how do you pass it to Jsonnet and get the result? I'm planning to use it on CI/CD. I'll supose you use the GO build to use Jsonnet, that's what i will do and generate the docker-compose JSON from a template for every CI.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just please test everything before you commit to it to ensure I've not missed an obvious gotcha! Or wait to see if someone else has a more elegant solution. I wrote a Jsonnet builder for Google Cloud Platform's Cloud Build service. Cloud Build (formerly Container Builder) is Google's CI|CD service. https://medium.com/@DazWilkin/a-jsonnet-builder-for-container-builder-71a0f6c18db7.